# StringOutofBoundsException when converting stringbuilder to character

Tags: java

I am attempting to compare two characters but am receiving a `StringOutOfBoundException` at the line `char E = guesstwo.charAt(C)`. How can I resolve this?

The relevant code is below:

```
class Hangman{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String guessedwords = "";
        Scanner keys = new Scanner(System.in);
        String phrase = keys.nextLine();
        int guesslim = keys.nextInt();
        String guess = keys.next();

        //phrase length for guessing & StringBuilder to allow modifications
        StringBuilder phrasetwo = new StringBuilder(phrase);
        StringBuilder guesstwo = new StringBuilder(guess);

        for (int i = 0; i < phrasetwo.length(); i++) {
            guessedwords += " _";  
        }
        //loop runs through all characters   
        for (int i = 0; i < phrasetwo.length(); i++) {      
            char d = phrasetwo.charAt(i);  
            char e = guesstwo.charAt(i); 
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `guesstwo.length()` within the bounds of `phrasetwo.length()`

Answer (score 0):

The String array is 0 based. The length() return the size of the array, but the last position of the array is the lenght less one. You must use "<=" in the condition part of the for.

"<=" Here.

```
for(int C = 0; C <= phrasetwo.length(); C++){

    char D = phrasetwo.charAt(C);  
    char E = guesstwo.charAt(C); 

     //if statement compares two characters
     if(E == D){
        System.out.println("That is a correct. Please guess again");
        guesstwo = keys.next();
        goodcount++;
     }
```

Comment: Thanks, I did try that and still get the same error on this line: char E = guesstwo.charAt(C);

Comment: But only on the second guess.

Comment: @jeblacker are you using it in the two for?

Answer (score 0):

In the following code:

```
//loop runs through all characters   
for (int i = 0; i < phrasetwo.length(); i++) {      
    char d = phrasetwo.charAt(i);  
    char e = guesstwo.charAt(i); 
    ...
}
```

`i` takes the values from `0` to `phrasetwo.length - 1`. It then references the characters at position `i` in both `phrasetwo` and `guesstwo`. If `phrasetwo` is longer than `guesstwo` then the statement where the error occurs will be attempting to reference a character past the end of the string. Hence the error.